# static ip address rootless containers

Tags: firewall, home-networking, reverse-proxy, container, podman

Is there any possibilities of allocating custom internal static ip address for podman rootless containers. And then expose them securely to the public internet through reverse proxy without opening extra ports from the host.

Comment: I don't know anything about Podman rootless containers, but do either of these help: https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/7842 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59888892/assigning-specific-ip-address-to-containers-using-podman ? - Probably the latter

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's an option for pod create, run:

> --ip=ipv4
>
> ---
>
> Specify a static IPv4 address for the <<container|pod>>, for example 10.88.64.128.

https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/options/ip.html

Comment: I was looking for a way for internal host ip address. Anyway thanks for this. It will help